# How to filter not only by outerref id in a subquery?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a problem with filtering by boolean field in a subquery.
For example, I have two models: Good and Order.

```
class Good(models.Model):
    objects = GoodQuerySet.as_manager()

class Order(models.Model):
   good = models.FK(Good, related_name="orders")
   is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to calculate how many completed orders has each good.
I implemented a method in Good's manager:

```
class GoodQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def completed_orders_count(self):
        subquery = Subquery(
            Order.objects.filter(good_id=OuterRef("id"))
                .order_by()
                .values("good_id")
                .annotate(c=Count("*"))
                .values("c")
        )
        return self.annotate(completed_orders_count=Coalesce(subquery, 0))
```

This method counts all existing orders for a good, but it works when I call it like this:

```
Good.objects.completed_orders_count().first().completed_orders_count
```

To get the correct value of completed orders I tried to add filter `is_completed=True`. The final version looks like this:

```
class GoodQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def completed_orders_count(self):
        subquery = Subquery(
            Order.objects.filter(good_id=OuterRef("id"), is_completed=True)
                .order_by()
                .values("good_id")
                .annotate(c=Count("*"))
                .values("c")
        )
        return self.annotate(completed_orders_count=Coalesce(subquery, 0))
```

If I try to call `Good.objects.completed_orders_count().first().completed_orders_count`  I got an error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field.`

Comment: You need to include output_field argument.
Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/